# ajax php mail function not working for hotmail addresses

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with my contact form and the php mail() function. For some reason, they work for every email address (@gmail, @yahoo, @outlook and even @facebook!) except the old dreaded hotmail. I am just curious as to where my code is missing something. I have checked the mail servers and there is apparently no issue with hotmail addresses.

The email does not even get delivered to the spam/junk folder (it does not reach hotmail). I had a look online and some say to change the headers to avoid being caught in the spam filter. Any pointers to this?

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'companyname@mail.com'; 
    $to = 'myemail@hotmail.com'; 
    $subject = $name . ' has sent you a message';
    $human = $_POST['antispam'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if (isset($_POST['name']) && $human == '4') {                
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '{"status":"1"}';
        } else { 
            echo '{"status":"0"}';
        } 
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '{"status":"2"}';
    }
?>
```

The if statements is just a check if all forms are valid and the anti spam (2+2) is correctly entered. nothing much to do in this part. The issue I guess is somewhere in the header

Answer (score 0):

Try using these changes:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    ...
    $from = 'companyname@mail.com'; 
    $headers = 'From: '. $from. "\r\n";
    ...
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
    ...
?>
```

4th parameter of mail function is expected to be additional_headers, not just from address.

Comment: tried the above. Still not working.It works with all others except Hotmail